# What is the correct way to create methods that change private fields in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, field

I just switched to C# from Java and just became familiar with the notion of Property, which seems to be the common way of getting and setting field values.

So what should I do if I need to update the field values pretty often, but not setting them to totally new values? Like, there is a field in my class that is a List, and I need to sometimes append elements into it, while keeping the rest of the List unchanged. Should I just go ahead and create a method like

```
void append(Point p) { }
```

or is there a more elegant or civilized way of doing this in C#?

Comment: You could expose the List as a property `List<Point> Points { get; set; }` and call Add/Remove on it.

Comment: How do you add items to a list while keeping the rest of the list unchanged? How is that different from just adding items to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single "correct" way of setting private fields through an API. The answer depends on what functionality you would like to present to your users.

If you would like to let them access your `List<Point>` as a read-only collection which they can modify in any way they like, you may present your list as a read-only property:

```
public IList<Point> Points {get;} = new List<Point>();
```

If you think that this approach gives your users too much freedom, and you would prefer to have tighter control over the points that appear on the list, you may want to expose a property for accessing the list as `IEnumerable<Point>` and a bunch of methods for adding / removing / modifying points on the list.

```
private IList<Point> points = new List<Point>();
public IEnumerable<Point> Points => points;
public void AddPoint(Point p) {
    // validate p before inserting on the list,
    ...
    points.Add(p);
}
```

**Note:** Code examples above use C# 6 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to allow modification to the list but not allow the instance to be changed you could write
`public IList<Point> MyPointList {get; private set;}`

However if you wanted to only support adding elements, then the add method would be a good way to go.

Comment: lol, I actually didn't put that together when I came up with the name.  It's just something that I say.  :D

Answer (score 0):

C# syntax is simple and elegant and a joy to write with. In a Class you can create a private field that backs up a public getter and setter. From within this Class, you can set or get the private field as you like. If a different Class needed to access the field, it would need to use the public getter and setter. Example: A private List could be created and edited from within the class however you choose to. With a custom add method or using the List .Add method. From a different class you would simply call the public List properties .Add method. There really is just one private List that is being edited. You can create another private List for another task. Maybe a staging area for items waiting to be validated before entering the main list.